# Can't get Capistrano to call bundle and rake commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

I can't get Capistrano to run bundle commands and rake commands.
I get debug logs like this:

```
DEBUG [0f557e7e]    /usr/bin/env: bundle
DEBUG [0f557e7e]    : No such file or directory
```

I have RVM on all ma computers (dev and production)

Here's my config:

## deploy.rb

```
lock '3.1.0'

set :application, 'blog'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:xxx/yyyy.git'

set :deploy_to, '/home/joel/apps/blog'

set :deploy_via, :copy


set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.1.0p0'
set :default_env, { rvm_bin_path: '/home/joel/.rvm/bin:$PATH' }

SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake] = "#{fetch(:default_env)[:rvm_bin_path]}/rvm ruby-#{fetch(:rvm_ruby_version)} do bundle exec rake"


namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  desc 'Migrate db'
  task :migrate do
    on primary :db do
      within release_path do
          execute :rake, 'db:migrate'
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Bundle install'
  task :bundle do
    on primary :app do
      within release_path do
          execute :bundle, 'install'
      end
    end
  end


  after :publishing, :restart

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end
```

## production.rb

```
role :app, %w{xxx@yyy.com}
role :web, %w{xxx@yyy.com}
role :db,  %w{xxx@yyy.com}
server 'yyy.com', user: 'xxx', roles: %w{web app}, my_property: :my_value
```

## capfile

```
require 'capistrano/setup'

require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'


Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

and when I try to call

```
cap production deploy:bundle
```

if I want to call `bundle:install` on the production server, here's what I get :

```
 INFO [0f557e7e] Running /usr/bin/env bundle install on yyy.com
DEBUG [0f557e7e] Command: cd /home/joel/apps/blog/current && ( RVM_BIN_PATH=/home/joel/.rvm/bin:$PATH /usr/bin/env bundle install )
DEBUG [0f557e7e]    /usr/bin/env: bundle
DEBUG [0f557e7e]    : No such file or directory
```

Although, if I ssh onto the server and copy-paste that command, it works fine. (and the same thing happens with take commands, like `rake db:migrate`). I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the paths, so here's my

## `rvm info`

```
ruby-2.1.0:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux li101-172 3.12.6-x86_64-linode36 #2 SMP Mon Jan 13 18:54:10 EST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "ubuntu/12.04/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         "/usr/bin/zsh => zsh 4.3.17 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.25.14 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "15 days 19 hours 42 minutes 40 seconds ago"
    path:         "/home/joel/.rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.1.0p0"
    date:         "2013-12-25"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2013-12-25 revision 44422"
    full_version: "ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0"
    ruby:         "/home/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin:/home/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin:/home/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin:/home/joel/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0:/home/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0"
    IRBRC:        "/home/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

## edit:

I also tried removing all paths, and using `PermitUserEnvironment` in ~/.ssh/environment

and changing my task to loo

```
  desc 'Bundle install'
  task :bundle do
    on primary :app do
      within release_path do
          execute 'source ~/.zshrc && cd ~/apps/blog/current/ && bundle install'
          execute 'source ~/.zshrc && cd ~/apps/blog/current/ && RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate'
          execute 'source ~/.zshrc && cd ~/apps/blog/current/ && RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile'
      end
    end
  end
```

and it works. So the problem was really with the paths, but is there a way to use symbols to avoid using the `source` and `cd` ?

Comment: A couple of thoughts: Could it be related with your deploy env permissions? or the folder from which capistrano is issuing the commands? Maybe the symbols you're using for command names (try with commas). Notice how the error says that `:` isn't a file or folder.

Comment: What do you mean? Like where I write `execute :bundle, 'install'` ? If so, what would you write, I'm not sure to understand.

Comment: I mean `execute 'bundle install'` just as if you wanted capistrano to paste the text as a command.

Comment: Yeah I get that now : `Command: bundle install -- zsh:1: command not found: bundle`

Comment: At least now the command is being properly called. Are you using `rvm-capistrano gem`?

Comment: No I'm using   `gem 'capistrano-rvm'` . Also, you were very close, I now have something working, but it's quite hacky... See my edit.

Comment: Check the differences between both gems (are they really different?). I don't think I can help much more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling RVM and my path problems were solved. I still don't know why it works, but it works.